# Select box not working properly in mozilla

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, drop-down-menu

I don't know whats happening with the select box in firefox. It works fine in chrome and Edge. but not in Firefox. Please help guys.

The select field has 50 options to choose from but its all stacked in a horizontal way in firefox. What may be causing this problem.
Please check this [link](http://wearenakshatra.com/client-tests/)

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: I just checked on FF and chrome on MAC, they both look the same. Can you at least post a screenshot of what you are seeing? Add the select code if you can

Comment: Please provide the HTML and CSS you are using.

Comment: The code is same as it is in the above link, I have it in a blank page.

Comment: While I can duplicate the behaviour in Windows 8.1, this is not how to ask questions. See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1016716). What you should do is produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @MrLister FYI its working fine in codepen and jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your ids have a property `display: initial` and firefox doesn't like it. If you set all of the options to be `width: 100% and display: block`, and take off the display initial property from the ids or use important, then your problem will be solved in firefox.

Example:

```
option {
  width: 100%;
  display: block !important;
}
```

If you do not wish to use the !important declaration, then you can remove the `display: initial` property from #accounty3id, #account4id, etc.

Comment: You don't even have to set any properties. Just removing the `display` property works fine.

Comment: Yea I don't see any reason to set a display property for any of the `option` tags. Remove them all and it should look normal

Comment: Yeah, it worked. I set the display to block. Thanks @Ian J Miller

Comment: Glad it worked! And @Huangism you are correct, I just gave an alternative to that as well.